# How to make definitions inside root package objects accessible to inner packages directly?

Tags: scala, import, package

Assume that an application has following package structure:

```
root_package
- inner_package1
  - inner_0
  - inner_1
- inner_package2
```

So, `root_package` is the parent package. Similarly, packages `inner_package1`, `inner_package2` are packages defined inside the parent package and so on..

Now, we know that Scala allows us to put together common definitions, variables, methods etc needed by the codebase within the package using a **package object**.

Here, I define define a **package object** for `root_package` as follow:

```
package object root_package {

  type Dictionary = Map[String, Any]
}
```

Now, the type `Dictionary` becomes directly usage to the codebase placed at 1-level under `root_package`, but can't be directly accessible from inner packages and deeper nested levels.(*It can only be done using import which somewhat defeats the purpose for me*).

Is there some way where I can define **package objects** such that the common definitions are directly accessible to all the sub-packages or inner-packages without additional import statements ?

Comment: Unnested packaging?

Comment: In the nested files you can do this: `package foo` `package bar` rather than `package foo.bar` that way, all that is defined inside `foo` is available.

Comment: @Johny T Koshy Interesting. But, do you think its reasonable when "common usage of definitions/type/variables" is a criteria that dictates how we package/group classes ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez But, that would affect all the classes as well right ? I mean the access of the classes defined inside those nested packages get affected ?

Comment: What do you mean the access of those classed gets affected? If you think the classes will be available in both packages then no, they will be part of `foo.bar` that is just sugar syntax for `package foo.bar` & `import foo._`

Comment: Ah I see. That a great trick ! Small note: `package foo` `package bar` doesn't work. It requires semicolon in between. So, `package foo`; `package bar` works :) This will mean that I will have apply this syntactic sugar to many many classes (in my case 100s). But definitely this is an approach that can be used.

Comment: @oblivion This doesn't require a semicolon. Just `package foo` `package bar` are two lines, not one line. If you put them to the same line then yeah, you have to separate them with a semicolon.